# cakephp link image to view

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to link the following image:

```
echo '<img src="'.Configure::read('CDN').'/img/'.Configure::read("Config.language").'/my_bird.png" alt="Bird" />';
```

to this view:

```
<a href="<?=$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'birds', 'action' => 'view'))?>">
```

How do I do that? I've seen examples with echo $this->Html-> link but I'm not sure how to do it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `echo $this->Html->image();`.

```
    echo $this->Html->image(Configure::read('CDN') . '/img/' . Configure::read("Config.language") . '/my_bird.png', array(
        "alt" => "Bird",
        'url' => array('controller' => 'birds', 'action' => 'view')
    ));
```